# store pci address in memory and display

Tags: assembly, x86, pci

[run screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXQDZ.png)

*Sorry, English isn’t my first language, so please excuse any mistakes.*

When I read the pci address(from 80000000h), I try to determine whether it is a valid address (not equal to ffffh), and store the valid address in the variable address, and read it in the next loop.
But my code doesn't seem to be able to achieve it. When reading, it does not display the stored content, but some garbled.
I don't know if it's the wrong way to store or read it, I'm still new to using offset access.

```
.MODEL SMALL
.486P
.DATA
;-----------------------------------------
rowx     db ?
count     db ?
address  dw 500 dup(?)
fun      db 0
bus      db ?
dev      db ?
.STACK  500
.CODE
;*****************************************

pcitool proc near
    open_11:
        mov esi,offset address
        mov edi,80000000h   
        
        mov count,0    ;Count the number of devices
        mov rowx,0     ;like 'count' 
        
    loopaa: 
        push cx
        
        mov eax,edi     ;read address
        mov dx,0cf8h
        out dx,eax
        mov dx,0cfch
        in  eax,dx
        
        cmp ax,0ffffh   ;Comparison
        jz  again1      ;if equal to ffffh move next loop
        mov eax,edi     ;else store it
        ;----------
        push eax
                
        mov  cl,16
        shr  eax,cl
        and al, 80h
        mov  bus,al        ;check bus
        
        pop eax
        push eax
        
        mov  cl,11
        shr  eax,cl
        and  al,1fh    ;check device
        mov  dev,al
        
        pop eax
        push eax
        
        mov eax,edi     ;else store it
        mov cl,8
        shr eax,cl
        and al,07h
        mov fun,al        ;check function
        
        pop eax

           ;---------------------

        inc rowx        ;add dev
        
        mov eax,edi
        shr eax,8
        mov [esi],ax
        add esi,2

        ; mov [esi],edi           ;store
        ; add esi,4               

        cmp fun,0       ;have function?
        jnz again1      ;yes -> again
        
        ; add edi,0ch     ;no function
        ; mov eax,edi     ;addr+12
        lea eax, [edi+0ch]
        
        mov dx,0cf8h            ;read
        out dx,eax
        mov dx,0cfch
        in  eax,dx
        
        sub edi,0ch     
        mov cl,16   
        shr eax,cl      
        and al,80h
        
        cmp al,0
        jnz again1
        jnz again1
        add edi,700h
        
    again1: 
        add edi,100h
        cmp edi,81000000h
        jb loopaa
        
;------------------read from memory-----------------

    opena:  
        mov esi,offset address


    loopa: 
        mov eax,[esi]
        
        mov  cl,16
        shr  eax,cl
        mov dl,al
        mov ah,02h
        int 21h

        mov  cl,11
        shr  eax,cl
        and  al,1fh    ;check device
        mov dl,al
        mov ah,02h
        int 21h

        mov cl,8
        shr eax,cl
        and al,07h
        mov dl,al
        mov ah,02h
        int 21h
        

        inc count        ;account
    again: 
        mov al,rowx
        cmp count,al
        jz endd
        add esi,4
        loop loopa         ;loop read
    
    endd:
        mov     ax,4c00h    ;esc
        int     21h
        ret

pcitool   endp
```

Comment: What does it actually display?  What hardware are you running this on?  Are you assembling+linking this MASM(?) code into a DOS `.exe` and running it on bare metal?  That info would be important for a [mcve].  Presumably not under an OS like Linux which would stop you from using `in`/`out` without system calls to set the IOPL.  Have you tested your output functions with known data, to make sure that isn't the problem?  Can you single-step this with a debugger?  There are some DOS debuggers that might be usable, I think.

Comment: When computing the bus/device/function, it needs to reload eax from edi before each shr. Otherwise it computes dev as edi >> 27 and fun as edi >> 35. So fun is always 0.

Comment: At the label `opena`, probably you want to load cx with `rowx`. At the label `again`, it pops cx on each iteration, but cx hasn't been pushed.

Comment: The code in `loopa` seems to assume that eax is a parameter to cRead_PCI, dev_ven_id, and class_name, and it also seems to assume that these functions don't change eax.

Comment: `loopaa` loops 70000 times even though it skips all the functions for devices that don't exist (and that would be too many iterations anyway). It should stop when edi reaches 81000000. Instead of `loop loopaa`, use `cmp edi, 81000000h; jb loopaa`. (Then you can get rid of the push cx and pop cx.)

Comment: @prl I need to modify the code, but am I thinking right? This loop can store addresses like an array.

Comment: Yes, if you fix the few problems, it will store the addresses of existing PCI devices in the `address` array and the number  of devices  in `rowx`.

Comment: PCI BDFs are 16 bits, so you might consider changing `address` array to `dw` and store into it using `mov eax, edi; shr eax, 8; mov [esi], ax; add esi, 2`.

Comment: A couple more comments: 1. Instead of `add edi, 0ch; mov eax, edi; sub edi, 0ch` use `lea eax, [edi+0ch]`.  2. Instead of `mov cl, 16; shr eax, cl; and al, 80h; cmp al, 0; jnz again1` use `test eax, 1<<23; jnz again1`.

Comment: @prl where to using `mov eax, edi; shr eax, 8; mov [esi], ax; add esi, 2`

Comment: `test eax, 1<<23; jnz again1`can be used`shl`?